# Google authentication and gmail access in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2, gmail

I am working on a JSF application.

1. In which a user should be able to login with gmail/google apps account (redirected to google login page and returned after authentication)
2. and user should be able to check/delete emails (using Java Gmail) in the subsequent screen.

This application is to be hosted in jboss/tomcat server and not in GAE appspot.

I checked examples to create login and logout urls using GAE API or OAuth2.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview

But it seems it is not possible to access gmail after authentication in the above method.

If somebody can provide any inputs, it is highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What are you asking help with? checking the mail? reading/deleting?

Comment: Google Mail Feed is only available for Gmail accounts on Google Apps domains.

Comment: @greedybuddha I wonder if I can access mailbox with full control using Java mail after google's authentication, so that user doesnt have to enter password in my website.